# Still no Codename One Library project option when using Eclipse?

Tags: codenameone

I recently read [FIRST CLASS ECLIPSE SUPPORT](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/first-class-eclipse-support.html) which made me expect a cn1lib-wizard. But there still is none, right?

Answer (score 0):

The gist of the article is that we will update the Eclipse plugin with the NetBeans & IntelliJ versions. With the trend of migrating towards common code across IDE's within our plugin (the new settings UI) this should be much easier and Eclipse should no longer be out of date with the other IDE's.

I'm not sure when we'll get around to do the library template, unlike the other features it requires some work since the Ant implementation on Eclipse is rather different. So it's hard to give a specific date.